# my unity public variable is not being assigned a sound clip

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine

```
public class PlayerCollision : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool doorIsOpen = false;
    float doorTimer = 0.0f;
    public float doorOpenTime  = 3.0f;
    public AudioClip doorOpenSound; 
    public AudioClip doorShutSound;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    void OnControllerColliderHit(ControllerColliderHit hit){
        if(hit.gameObject.tag == "playerDoor" && doorIsOpen == false){ 
            //doorIsOpen = true;
            OpenDoor(hit.gameObject);
        }           
    }

    void OpenDoor(GameObject door){      
        door.audio.PlayOneShot(doorOpenSound,1);
    }

}
```

[image]

the above, I initiated my 2 public variables with open and close door sound clips

when I debug the code, the variables turn up null

[image]

Comment: Is this game object instantiated directly or via `Instantiate` from a prefab?